# Retrive user logged in Kerberos with Angular6

Tags: angular, authentication, angular6, single-sign-on, kerberos

My problem is as follow, 
i have a server with Apache and Kerberos to handle the SSO Authentication.
This server point to a different one using JKMount and i need to read the remote user with Angular6.

I know that the user is logged in as if i try to to check the user with a JSP with a response.getRemoteUser() i get the data i want, but if i try to do the same with Angular i find the body of the response null and i will not find that Value in the header.

The code in the Jsp that check if the user is logged in is a simple request.getRemoteUser()

I expect to find the user logged on Kerberos and read it with Angular

Did someone else stumble upon something similar?

Thanks,